# Skrollr sticky element from static to fixed not executing correctly

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, sticky, skrollr

I need an element to position fixed itself to the top of the viewport when the top of the element reaches the top of the viewport. To do that I'm using Skrollr plugin and I have used it on my element in this way:

```
<div id="top-bar" data-0="position:static;" data-5-top="position:fixed; top: 5px;"></div>
```

Instead of fix the element when this gets to the top of the viewport, it positions fixed it way before then. This happens in all browsers.

What am I doing wrong? Here is the dev site http://dev.thinktravellive.com/. The nav bar is the skrollr element.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix this issue with a small delay skrollr init() so I now have

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var s = skrollr.init({forceHeight: false});
}, 100);
```

Hope this helps someone